# Bot Framework ICredentialProvider. IsValidAppIdAsync & GetAppPasswordAsync never called when testing from Bot Framework Web Portal

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework c# webservice template. I created an implementation of IcredentialProvider to handle botAuthentication. This works great from the emulator. I am able to put the credentials in the emulator and validate them in my implementation of IcredentialProvider.

However, after deploying my web service externally (does use ssl) and testing from the web portal test client it seems that the functions IsValidAppIdAsync and GetAppPasswordAsync of the credentialprovider are never called.

This seems odd to me because when running locally with the emulator I can step through the calls to isvalidappidasync and getapppasswordasync, but they do not seem to get executed in my externally deployed code when testing from the web portal test client.

Execution gets to the IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync function of the provider and seems to stop after that. I always return false from IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync indicating that i always want to do authentication.

Call messages going through the externally hosted code are coming back as unauthorized.

Comment: Please share the code and how you are initializing the ICredentialProvider.  Also, what "webservice template" did you use to create the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that may run into this issue. The issue turned out to be our company firewall rule was blocking login.botframework.com therefore the botframework could not call out to validate.

Comment: I also found this document that has all of the endpoints that need to be whitelisted [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-bot-framework-faq#security-and-privacy] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-bot-framework-faq#security-and-privacy